# AWS APIGateway CloudFormation specify Api Key required for method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have the below CloudFormation template which creates my API Gateway (backed by Lambda). I want to enable API Keys as a requirement for one or more of these methods. I have successfully created API Keys, Usage Plans and the association between the two, but can't figure out how to actually enable the 'requires API Key' property for some of the methods. The documentation from AWS specifies an '*ApiKeyRequired*' property as a part of the **AWS::ApiGateway::Method** component, but my CF template doesn't have or use this component? I'm unsure how to use it considering I've never required it before?

My template is below:

```
   "ServerlessRestApi": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "Properties": {
            "Description":"This is a placeholder for the description of this web api",
            "ApiKeySourceType":"HEADER",
            "Body": {
                "info": {
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "title": {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    }
                },
                "paths": {
                    "/list/tables": {
                        "get": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                "httpMethod": "POST",
                                "type": "aws_proxy",
                                "uri": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetTableList.Arn}/invocations"
                                }
                            },
                            "security": [
                                {
                                   "api_key": []
                                }
                             ],
                            "responses": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "/list/columns/{tableid}": {
                        "get": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                "httpMethod": "POST",
                                "type": "aws_proxy",
                                "uri": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetColumnList.Arn}/invocations"
                                }
                            },
                            "responses": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "datagw/general/table/get/{tableid}": {
                        "get": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                "httpMethod": "POST",
                                "type": "aws_proxy",
                                "uri": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetTableResponse.Arn}/invocations"
                                }
                            },
                            "responses": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "/": {
                        "get": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                "httpMethod": "POST",
                                "type": "aws_proxy",
                                "uri": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Get.Arn}/invocations"
                                }
                            },
                            "responses": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "/tables/{tableid}/{columnid}": {
                        "get": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                "httpMethod": "POST",
                                "type": "aws_proxy",
                                "uri": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetTableBasic.Arn}/invocations"
                                }
                            },
                            "responses": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "securityDefinitions": {
                        "type": "api_key",
                        "name": "x-api-key",
                        "in": "header"
                      }
                },
                "swagger": "2.0"
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think adding `security` under each path and then `securityDefinitions` under `paths` would work.

```
"paths": {
  "/list/tables": {
     "get": {
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
           "httpMethod": "POST",
           "type": "aws_proxy",
           "uri": {
              "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015- 
               03-31/functions/${GetTableList.Arn}/invocations"
           }
        },
        "security": [
           {
              "api_key": []
           }
        ]
     }
  }
},
"securityDefinitions": {
  "type": "api_key",
  "name": "x-api-key",
  "in": "header"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Athar - do I need to specify a key Id within the security > api_key value? (You've shown it as just empty brackets in your example)

Comment: That's the syntax to define security scopes in Swagger. So it should be just an empty array. See step # 2 Applying security in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

Comment: thanks I'll check it out today and if it pans out, i'll mark the question as answered. Thanks Athar, I really appreciate your time on this.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't seem to work. The method is linked to a usage plan, but it says the method does not require an API key. I'll update my post with my new template.

Comment: I've tried that solution and found that it does not force the method to require an API key. While the Swagger document expresses that the security required has been set, it does not influence the setting when deploying through Cloud Formation.

Comment: It created the API key but it does not enforce it. Under method request is says `API Key Required false`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by abandoning the use of the Body property in the AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi using:

```
 "ServerlessRestApi": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "DependsOn": "AspNetCoreFunction",
        "Properties": {
           "Description":"My Api Gateway",
            "ApiKeySourceType" : "HEADER",      
            "EndpointConfiguration" : {  "Types" : [ "REGIONAL" ]}
        }
    },
```

Then, I created a proxy resource. In your case, you would create a resource for each of your paths. Where I have, "{proxy+}", you would have "/list/tables."

```
"ProxyResource": {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
    "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": {
            "Ref": "ServerlessRestApi"
        },
        "ParentId": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ServerlessRestApi",
                "RootResourceId"
            ]
        },
        "PathPart": "{proxy+}"
    }
},
```

Finally, I was able to define an AWS::ApiGateway::Method then enforce usage an API key:

```
"CoreApiPostMethod":
  {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
     "DependsOn" : ["AspNetCoreFunction", "ServerlessRestApi"],
    "Properties":
    {
     "AuthorizationType" :"NONE",
      "OperationName" : "My API Post Request",

     "ApiKeyRequired" : true,
            "ResourceId": { "Ref": "ProxyResource"  },
    "RestApiId": {
      "Ref": "ServerlessRestApi"
    },
     "HttpMethod" : "POST",
      "Integration" : {  
       "ConnectionType" :  "INTERNET",
          "IntegrationHttpMethod" : "POST",
       "Type" : "AWS_PROXY",
        "Uri" : {
                          "Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AspNetCoreFunction.Arn}/invocations"
                }
      }        
    }

  },
```

And then follow the same pattern for the other HTTP methods. It's more verbose than the original configuration, but it does give you more control over the method configuration.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, it looks most like the solution that would suit me (although it's going to be hellishly verbose for all the paths I have :P)

Answer (score 2):

Complete guide [here](https://sarthakj178.com/using-aws-api-gateway-with-api-key-using-sam/). This guide provides a basic setup for enabling API keys for any API Gateway methods.

Use [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) for defining your API. It supports an [Auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html) attribute which has an attribute named ApiKeyRequired. Set this to true.

Following code snippet from the above guide should do.

```
AuthApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
       StageName: Prod
       Auth:
           ApiKeyRequired: 'true' # This makes passing ApiKey mandatory
       DefinitionBody:
           swagger: '2.0'
           info: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party.

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER",
```

And

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "<SOME_NAME>": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "x-api-key",
        "in": "header"
    }
 }
```

And

```
"security" : [{
    "<SOME_NAME>" : []
}]
```

So a possible working solution could be

```
              "Body": {
                    "swagger": "2.0",
                    "info": {
                        "version": "2017-01-27T21:44:58Z",
                        "title": {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}
                    },
                    "basePath": "/bbd",
                    "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER",
                    "schemes": [
                        "https"
                    ],
                    "paths": {
                        "/{proxy+}": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
                                "produces": [
                                    "application/json"
                                ],
                                "parameters": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "proxy",
                                        "in": "path",
                                        "required": true,
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "security" : [{
                                    "bbd" : []
                                }],
                                "responses": {},
                                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                    "responses": {
                                        "default": {
                                            "statusCode": "200"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "uri": "<URL>",
                                    "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
                                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                                    "cacheNamespace": "xh7gp9",
                                    "cacheKeyParameters": [
                                        "method.request.path.proxy"
                                    ],
                                    "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
                                    "type": "aws_proxy"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "securityDefinitions": {
                        "bbd": {
                            "type": "apiKey",
                            "name": "x-api-key",
                            "in": "header"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"security" : [{
                "myKey" : []
            }],

"myKey": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "x-api-key",
            "in": "header"
        },
```

Adding security element in body and myKey element in securityDefinitions worked for me.